# Sign XML document (XADES-BES) with PKCS12 Certificate (.p12) in PHP

Tags: php, xml, sign

I need to sign a XML document using a PKCS12 certificate (.p12 file) in PHP, the standard must be XADES-BES. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you manage to do so?

Comment: @Jorge Rojas did you manage to do so?

Comment: @cprn did you manage something in PHP regarding this?

Comment: @Surt did you manage something in PHP regarding this?

Comment: @Quamis I made my own lib but I've sold it so I can't share the final version. I think I can share something "pretty close" to final. There are some TODOs but AFAIK it's fully compliant with the standard. Unfortunately most services using XAdES use libs that aren't fully compliant and you might have to tweak some things, e.g. I had to integrate one bank that required different node order, another one needed a mixture of attached and detached signature - real world's a mess, have fun. ‍♂️ https://gist.github.com/cprn/d1c6f0b1f513a0536488ca0aff4d8721

Comment: @Quamis nop, I finally ended by delegating the signature to bakoffice so the client can select it's own "sign software"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely possible but equally likely has never been done with PHP code yet.

- [XML validation with XMLDSIG using XadES-BES algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4215343/367456)

Existing PHP XML Digital Signature libraries for example are:

- [xmlseclibs](https://code.google.com/p/xmlseclibs/)
- [FraGoTe/xmldsig](https://github.com/FraGoTe/xmldsig)
- [Maks3w/xmldsig](https://github.com/Maks3w/xmldsig/)

It's probably a good bet to built on top of *xmlseclibs*.