# PHP 7: Sign XML document with XADES-BES

Tags: php, xml, digital-signature

I need to sign an XML with XADES-BES ver. 1.4.1 enveloped Signature.

I've googled alot, but have not found any solution and neither any idea:

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173278/sign-xml-document-xades-bes-with-pkcs12-certificate-p12-in-php)
I installed and succesfully added a signature to an XML document using [xmlseclibs](https://code.google.com/p/xmlseclibs/)  library.

But this (seems me) does not support XADES-BES and my poor skills do not allow me to go further.

Can suggest me a path to the solution?

Thanks